# Equality statement with both sides bound universally

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This is a rather naïve question...

$\forall x\forall y(x=y)$

Does this say that every member of the domain is the same (has the same value), or vacuously that each member of the domain is equal to itself?

My understanding was the former, where each bound variable ranges over the entire domain independently; however, something I just read in a book made me second guess. It said that the above could be replaced by $\forall x(x=x)$, and I became unsure of which way to read it.

Based on Bram28's original answer, here is the text that confused me:

> 1. $\mathfrak U_i$ only has universal quantifiers. We bring the matrix of $\mathfrak U_i$ into conjunctive normal form. Each conjunction term of the matrix is a disjunction of formulas of the form $\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b$ or $\overline{\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b}$, including the case when there is only one such formula. If a conjunction term contains a disjunction term $\overline{\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b}$ with different variables $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$, we delete $\overline{\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b}$ and replace $\mathfrak a$ by $\mathfrak b$ in all occurences of $\mathfrak a$ in the conjunction term. If the conjunction term consists only of $\overline{\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b}$, we replace it by $\overline{\mathfrak b = \mathfrak b}$ This is repeated as often as possible, vacuous quantifiers being deleted, until $\mathfrak U_i$ is transformed into a reduced formula. The transformation of $\mathfrak U_i$ is an equivalence transformation.

Ackermann, *Solvable Cases of the Decision Problem*

Did I misread this in believing that both $\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b$ and $\overline{\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b}$ can both be transformed, when it's really saying to only transform the latter? (which would make a lot more sense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the former, since for $x$ and $y$ you could pick different objects.

Thus, if there are different objects in the domain, then you would be able to pick different objects, and then of course $x =y$ is no longer true. So, given that $\forall x \forall y (x = y)$ is true, it must be the case that there are not two different objects in the domain, i.e that there is only one object in the domain.

$\forall x (x=x)$ says that every object is identical to itself... which is of course always true, no mater how many objects are in the domain. Thus, these two statements are *not* equivalent!

A final quick note: you say 'have the same value' ... the identity $=$ in logic is one of *true* identity, i.e. if we say $x=y$ we don't just say that $x$ and $y$ have the same value, but that they are one and the same object.

Comment: So, I believe that means I misunderstood the (alleged) equivalence between $\forall x\forall y(x=y)$ and $\forall x(x=x)$. Should I post the actual text into the question? It's 2 paragraphs.

Comment: @Lugh Yeah, please post it, because they are definitely not equivalent!

Comment: done. on another note, why can't I start comments with @Bram28? I can do it with other users.

Comment: Regarding identity, I am confused regarding numerals. For {2,2}, they are still the same object '2', or two objects with the same value? Regardless of numerals, how can any singular object be in the domain twice?

Comment: @Lugh You can, it's just unnecessary since Bram28 will already be notified of any comments on his answer (such as this one).

Comment: @Lugh $2$ is a numeral that denotes the number we all know as '2' ... and yes, there is only one of them.  A set $\{ 2,2 \}$ is therefore really just the set $\{ 2 \}$. And so no, a singular object is never in the domain twice.  What you *can* do, however, is to have multiple *names* or *labels* for the same object. Indeed, when $a = b$, then we are using two different labels $a$ and $b$, but apparently they denote the same object.

Comment: @Lugh  About that paragraph ... That's part of a larger context yet, and I would have to see that to see what the author is trying to do, but suffice it to say that this is in no way intended to say that $a=b$ and $b=b$ are the same claim, let alone that $\forall x \forall y (x=y)$ is equivalent to $\forall x (x=x)$

Comment: Thank-you, with your input I believe that I have the answer that I need (I'm not going to paste several pages worth of text...but I do believe that you resolved my confusion).

Comment: btw, philosophically I would argue on the side of nominalism that '2' is just a label for two '1's :)

Comment: Either there is only one object in the domain of quantification, or there are none. In standard FOL, of course, the domain of quantification (or discourse) is assumed to be non-empty.